# Longest palindrome subsequence VS Longest subsequence whose reverse is also a subsequence

Tags: dynamic, reverse, palindrome, subsequence

I'm trying to think what is the difference between these two problems

Given a sequence S

1) Find the longest palindrome subsequence of S.

2) Find  the longest subsequence of S whose reverse is also a subsequence of S. The two subsequences could be the same.
Original phrasing is :Find the longest subsequence S' of S, such that there is a subsequence that is the same as as S' and a subsequence that is the reverse of S'.

The DP formulations I derived for the two problems are the same.

Are they actually the same problems? I've been trying to think this way:
Suppose the longest palindrome subsequence is `longestP`, then `longestP` itself is clearly a possible answer to 2).

Could there be a longer answer to 2)? Suppose there is one, called `longerP`, then the reverse of `longerP` is also a subsequence of S, call it `reverseLongerP`. Overlapped or not, a longer palindrome could be constructed from `longerP` and `reverseLongerP`. Thus contradictory to our assumption that `longestP` is the longest palindrome.

Could there be a shorter answer to 2)? I don't think so, since 2) asks us to find the longest subsequence of such kind, and `longestP` is already a possible answer, any subsequence that is shorter than `longestP` shouldn't be considered.

Above is my thinking to this problem, anything I'm missing?

My conclusion is that they are the same questions. However, I was asked to give a sequence that contains a string s which is not a palindrome and its reverse, as subsequences, while this sequence has no palindromes that are longer than s. I don’t think it’s possible.

My thinking is that, suppose such a sequence exists, then s and its reverse could form a palindrome with length of `length_of_s + length_of_reverse_s - length_of_overlap`, so the min length of this palindrome would be `length_of_s`. But in that case, `length_of_overlap` equals to `length_of_s`, so s and its reverse must be the same, s must be a palindrome, which would violate the s cannot be a palindrome restriction.

Answer (score 0):

Okay I got where I was wrong. It's not guaranteed that s and reverse_of_s could form a palindrome. It's really easy to see this but I've been stuck in my wrong assumption.
`4 3 1 2 3 4 2 1` is a good example.

Comment: Okay I think I got it wrong, 43134 would be the answer to both 1 and 2, same answer again.